# How to setup hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy to legacy in springboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

Due to dependencies upgrade:

- spring-boot-starter-parent:2.7.1 -> 3.0.0
- mysql:mysql-connector-java -> com.mysql:mysql-connector-j

I started to use `hibernate-core-6.1.5` with his new strategy to give names to tables.
So now tests are broken because when I want to save data to some some table a "_SEQ" is added to the table's name and the test won't find the table.

Investigating I finded some source:

- https://thorben-janssen.com/things-to-know-when-migrating-to-hibernate-6-x/#3_New_naming_strategy_for_default_sequences
- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-entitymanager
- [xmlns, xmlns:xsi, xsi:schemaLocation, and targetNamespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34202967/xmlns-xmlnsxsi-xsischemalocation-and-targetnamespace)
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2717
- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/Upgrading-to-Spring-Framework-6.x

To bypass the problem I'm specifying the strategy inside every entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "animal")
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)  // this will overwrite SEQUENCE
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
```

Could this be done in the application.yml?

Comment: Just specify the property as `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy` as with other hibernate specific properties.

Comment: I'll retry, at first this didn't work

Comment: ```spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy``` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [M. Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2696260/m-deinum) the problem is solved.

Now my application.yml is:

```yaml
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy: legacy
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming:
  implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
  physical-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

spring:
  profiles.active: dev
  jpa.hibernate.use-new-id-generator-mappings: false
  jpa.properties.jakarta.persistence.sharedCache.mode: ALL
  hibernate.show_sql: true
  flyway.out-of-order: false

# other stuff
```

## update

As of today I have new informations:

> Hibernate changes its GeneratedType.AUTO strategy since 5.2

### this is another solution

application.yml

```yaml
spring:
  profiles.active: dev
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlite:/data.db
    driver-class-name: org.sqlite.JDBC
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.community.dialect.SQLiteDialect

---

spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile: dev
  main:
    banner-mode: off
  # jpa.show-sql: true

logging.level:
  root: INFO
  level: DEBUG
  org.springframework.web: DEBUG
  org.hibernate.type: DEBUG
  # org.hibernate.SQL: DEBUG
```

The Entity:

```kotlin
@Entity
@Table(name = "files")
@Data
class FileEntity() {

    constructor(originalFilename: String, calculateHash: String) : this() {
        this.filename = originalFilename
        this.hash = calculateHash
    }

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "gen", strategy = "increment")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "gen")
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private var id: Long? = null

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private var filename: String? = null

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private var hash: String? = null
}
```

source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/11390603/16988820