Hibernate Envers 6.2.6.Final throws REVINFO_SEQ.nextval sequence not found
I migrated my project from Spring Boot 2.7.18 to 3.2.11 and Hibernate and Hibernate Envers from 5 to 6.2.6.Final.
With Spring boot 2.7.18 and Hibernate 5, services were running without any issues but after the migration, in insert or update operations, it throws below error

select REVINFO_SEQ.nextval from dual; ORA-02289 sequence does not exist.

After googling I tried below options,
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy=legacy

spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

but it is still throwing REVINFO_SEQ not found error. I also tried with value "single" instead of "legacy" for spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.db_structure_naming_strategy but still it didn't work.
Is there any workaround for this?

hmm see if this helps you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75917729/how-to-setup-hibernate-id-db-structure-naming-strategy-to-legacy-in-springboot

Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened.
